# How to convert long value 20130901 into smalldatetime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I have a long value `20130901`, how could I convert it to `smalldatetime`:

```
2013-09-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), 20130901));
```

Or just as a `DATETIME` (which can be implicitly or explicitly converted to a `SMALLDATETIME` *if* you need to):

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 0, CONVERT(CHAR(8), 20130901));
```

However, why not [`DATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx)? Why bother using `SMALLDATETIME` or `DATETIME` to carry the time too, if the time is always 0 (midnight)?

Also, why are you storing / passing this as a long? What's preventing someone from sending you `20130231` or `99999999` or `70000099` or even values with a number of digits other than 8? We have date-related data types for a reason - so we don't do things like use longs for dates, which not only loses this validation [but also a whole host of other functionality](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), 20130901), 112)
```